# Running reliable Ubuntu on a Dell Vostro 3559

Tags: dell, dell-vostro

I have always had the need to run Ubuntu on my laptop. Sometime back I used a Dell D630 and was unable to run stable Ubuntu on the same. Recently I purchased a Dell Vostro 3559 which has the following configurations.

- 4GB of DDR3 RAM
- AMD Radeon R5 M315
- AMD Radeon R5 M335/M315 Graphics card

The problem I had been having for a long time I believe is with regard to graphics processing. Usually when I use the PC, it gets more heated with Ubuntu if I play high quality videos. My chrome cannot open as many tabs it would open had it been running windows. So yes, I have sacrificed a lot of performance just to use Ubuntu on my laptop. But I would really like to correct this. I must mention, the sounds work perfectly okay and everything else pretty much work amazingly well.

Another problem is when I put the PC to sleep and wake it up. Again, it would sometimes not even switch on. There are many a times I'm forced to remove the battery just to get the OS to boot again. When I have windows, it never happened that way. I hope this post is not misunderstood, I am not saying Windows is better (it actually not good) which is why I use Ubuntu despite its quarks.

I would sincerely help some advises for me to solve this problem.

here is a [link to my PC configs](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/servicetag/55G3Q72/drivers) if required.

Comment: Could you ask **one** question at a time? And in a way that's easier to read and understand, there's too much to read at the moment. Help us help you :)